# Get variable inside load function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this might probably been answered many times but I do not know the words to search for to find the answer. So here is the question.

I'm using javascript and I have

```
function getDataUrl( file ){
    var url = URL.createObjectURL( file ),
    canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    img = new Image,
    dataURL = '';

    img.load = function(){
        canvas.height = this.height;
        canvas.width = this.width;
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
    };

    img.src = url;
    return dataURL;
}
```

then on the input I have this,

```
$('#file-input').on('change', function(e){
    var dataUrl = getDataUrl( e.target.files[0] );
    console.log( dataUrl );
});
```

But it return empty string (the initial one). I want the base64 data that already generated inside load.

I've try something like this

```
function getDataUrl( file ){
//... codes

    img.load = function(){
        //... codes
        dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
        return dataUrl;
    };
}
```

but of course it can't since it return to the load function and not to it's parent function.

How do I get `dataUrl` value inside load function ?

Thanks

Comment: make your `dataUrl` a global variable, then its value will be shared across functions

Comment: @muneebShabbir I'm sorry, but that's just wrong in at least 2 ways: global vars are bad for reasons that should be obvious, and the variable doesn't have to be set when you're accessing it (it *may* be, but there is no guarantee).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker yes you are right, i misunderstood the code flow, in this case callback will be the only fine solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code, abbreviated, looks like this:

```
function getDataUrl() {
    dataURL = '';  

    img.load = function() {
        dataURL = 'Hello!';
    };

    return dataURL;
}
```

What `img.load = function` does is nothing *except* assign a function to `img.load`, the execution will then just continue with the return statement, meaning that your `dataURL` variable retains the original value.
You should realize that functions in Javascript van be assigned to variables just like a string or number can. It's doesn't need to be executed.
It may be a bit confusing, it's certainly different from many other languages, but you'll get the hang of it. Be sure to continue reading & learning about javascript.

You probably want to use `img.onload`, this will execute the function whenever the image is finished loading. But this can be *whenever*, maybe 1 second, maybe 10, maybe never.

What you need to do, is something like:

```
$('#file-input').on('change', function(e) {
    getDataUrl(e.target.files[0], function(dataUrl) {
        console.log(dataUrl);
    });
});

function getDataUrl(callback) {
    dataURL = '';  

    img.onload = function() {
        callback(dataUrl);
    };

    return dataURL;
}
```

Here you pass a function as an argument, an execute that function once the image finished loading, passing dataUrl as a parameter. This is a fairly common pattern in Javascript.

Comment: Yeah, it's work. Callback was a perfect solution. I've think about it before, but just don't know how to apply it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `load` event is asynchronous.  That means it occurs sometime in the future AFTER your `getDataURL()` function has completed.  Thus, you cannot return the value you want from the `getDataURL()` function because the image has not loaded yet and the load event handler has not yet been called.  So, instead, you need to think asynchronously and program in a way that deals with that.  The typical way of doing this is to pass in a callback function that will get called when the data is available and you can pass that data to the callback function.

There are many different ways to code this, but here's one way:

```
function getDataUrl( file, callback ){
    var url = URL.createObjectURL( file ),
    canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    img = new Image,
    dataURL = '';

    img.load = function(){
        canvas.height = this.height;
        canvas.width = this.width;
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
        // pass the dataURL to the callback function
        callback(dataURL);
    };

    img.src = url;
}

getDataUrl("myfile.jpg", function(dataURL) {
    // code here to use the dataURL        
});
```

Comment: yeah, finally I learned something about when to apply callback. Thanks.